# Can I import an account in Metamask using the 24-word mnemonic?

Tags: ethereum, metamask

I created an account using MEWConnect and saved the 24-word mnemonic. I would like to import it in Metamask.

Metamask accepts only the private key. I opened it in MEW-Application (browser-based) but I don't find anywhere where to export the private key or the JSON-file. Is it possible to get the private key for an account fo which I have only the 24-word mnemonic.

Comment: This is not a question for SO. Btw, did you try this? https://vintage.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info

Comment: Many thanks! I used MEW in 2017 and it was exactly what today has become the "vintage" wallet!